# Flutter Local Notifications how to show icon on top menu

Tags: flutter

Hi my notification works fine it also gives vibrate to phone but the icon and the notification is not showing on screen, u have to slider down and u can see it in upper menu. how can I make to show in screen

The app page, I want to show little icon here
[image: App page]

The upper menu on the phone is

[image: Upper menü]

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _advertService.showBanner();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    final android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    final iOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    final initSettings = InitializationSettings(android, iOS);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSettings,
        onSelectNotification: _onSelectNotification);
  }

  Future<void> _onSelectNotification(String json) async {
    final obj = jsonDecode(json);

    if (obj['isSuccess']) {
      OpenFile.open(obj['filePath']);
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Error'),
          content: Text('${obj['error']}'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> downloadStatus) async {
    final android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id', 'channel name', 'channel description',
        priority: Priority.High, importance: Importance.Max);
    final iOS = IOSNotificationDetails();
    final platform = NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
    final json = jsonEncode(downloadStatus);
    final isSuccess = downloadStatus['isSuccess'];

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, // notification id
        isSuccess ? 'Okay' : 'Fail',
        isSuccess
            ? 'Downloaded'
            : 'Failed',
        platform,
        payload: json);
  }
```

Comment: I just want to show icon in top of the screen

Answer (score -2):

first you will set Flutter Launcher Icons

1. Setup the config file

   ```
    dev_dependencies:
    flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

    flutter_icons:
    android: "launcher_icon"
    ios: true
    image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
   ```

If you name your configuration file something other than flutter_launcher_icons.yaml or pubspec.yaml you will need to specify the name of the file when running the package.

Note: If you are not using the existing pubspec.yaml ensure that your config file is located in the same directory as it.

2. Run the package

   ```
     flutter pub get
     flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
   ```

use this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)